# Написать метод, который проверяет состав массива из чисел 1 и 4

Tags: java

Помогите пожалуйста, старшие братья программисты. Не один час ломаю голову, перепробовал все, совсем запутался.

**Написать метод, который проверяет состав массива из чисел 1 и 4. Если в нем нет хоть одной четверки или единицы, то метод вернет false; Если содержится число отличное от 1 и 4, то метод вернет false**

Примеры:

```
[ 1 1 1 4 4 1 4 4 ] -> true
[ 1 1 1 1 1 1 ] -> false
[ 4 4 4 4 ] -> false
[ 1 4 4 1 1 4 3 ] -> false
```

Вот мой код, добиться выполнения все условий задачи никак не получается:

```
public class CompositionArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {1, 4, 1, 1};
        int value1 = 1;
        int value2 = 4;
        System.out.println("Array: " + Arrays.toString(array));
        checkArray(array, value1, value2);
    }

    public static void checkArray(int[] array, int value1, int value2) {
        boolean test1 = false;
        boolean test2 = false;
        for (int element : array) {
            if (element == value1)
                test1 = true;
            else if(element == value1)
                test2 = true;
        }
        System.out.println("Is " + value1 + " and " + value2 + " present in the array: " + (test1 && test2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Логично, что не работает, ведь `(element == value1 && element == value2)`, условие element=1, value1 = 1,  value2 = 4 никогда не выполнится.

Comment: приведите примеры на входе и выходе

Comment: Даже при входных данных данных 1 и 4 он все равно выдает False

Comment: Нужно убедиться, что в массиве идут чередуясь пары 1 и 4? А если встречаются другие числа, то сразу `false`?

Comment: @АлександрКиласония 1. Не надо вставлять чужой код из ответа в вопрос. 2. А если уж вставляешь, то делай это с умом, а не тупой копипастой. Тогда и результат будет подходящий.

Comment: Почти, но не совсем так. 1 и 4 могут не чередоваться. К примеру [1, 1, 1, 4 , 1, 4 , 4] или [4, 4, 4, 4, 1] и т. д. И если массив будет состоять из одних единиц или из одних четверок, то тоже необходимо вернуть false, в прочем как и если в массиве будет хоть одно другое число отличное от 1 или 4. Пример [ 1 1 1 4 4 1 4 4 ] -> true
[ 1 1 1 1 1 1 ] -> false
[ 4 4 4 4 ] -> false
[ 1 4 4 1 1 4 3 ] -> false

Comment: Понятно :) Пишите @ник, чтобы уведомление было об ответе :)

Comment: Удивительно, как такая простая задача вызвала такой общественный резонанс

Comment: @DeMmAge, а сколько лет надо покодить, чтобы она была простой? У меня опыта 6 месяцов на JavaRush

Comment: @JavaRush, я про количество ответов. Никогда не видел столько ответов на подобное. Даже модератор появился. И его минусанули. Ржач

Comment: @DeMmAge, Не надо смеха, не надо злости. Всем спасибо, кто отозвался. Ну а мы будем дальше стараться и постигать эту нелегкую науку)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Накодировал при помощи стимов, выглядит не оч элегантно. Зато работает.

```java
public static boolean checkArray(int[] array, int first, int second) {
        boolean containsWrong = IntStream.of(array).filter(i -> i != first).filter(i -> i != second).count() != 0;
        boolean containsFirst = IntStream.of(array).filter(i -> i == first).count() != 0;
        boolean containsSecond = IntStream.of(array).filter(i -> i == second).count() != 0;
        return !containsWrong && containsFirst && containsSecond;
    }
```

Comment: получилось очень забавно)

Answer (score 5):

Нужно просто перебрать через `if`/`else if`/`else` варианты:

```
    public static boolean checkArray(int[] array, int value1, int value2) {
        boolean containsValue1 = false;
        boolean containsValue2 = false;

        for (int value : array) {
            if (value == value1)
                containsValue1 = true;
            else if (value == value2)
                containsValue2 = true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        return containsValue1 && containsValue2;
    }
```

Тест

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        {
            int[] array = {1, 4, 1, 1};
            System.out.println("Array: " + Arrays.toString(array));
            System.out.println("Result: " + checkArray(array, 1, 4));
        }

        {
            int[] array = {1, 1, 1, 1};
            System.out.println("Array: " + Arrays.toString(array));
            System.out.println("Result: " + checkArray(array, 1, 4));
        }

        {
            int[] array = {4, 4, 4};
            System.out.println("Array: " + Arrays.toString(array));
            System.out.println("Result: " + checkArray(array, 1, 4));
        }

        {
            int[] array = {1, 4, 1, 4, 777};
            System.out.println("Array: " + Arrays.toString(array));
            System.out.println("Result: " + checkArray(array, 1, 4));
        }
    }
```

Результат:

```
Array: [1, 4, 1, 1]
Result: true
Array: [1, 1, 1, 1]
Result: false
Array: [4, 4, 4]
Result: false
Array: [1, 4, 1, 4, 777]
Result: false
```

Answer (score 3):

Без понятия в чем проблема, все работает нормально.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {1, 4, 1, 1};
        int value1 = 1;
        int value2 = 4;
        System.out.println("Array: " + Arrays.toString(array));
        boolean result = checkArray(array, value1, value2);
        System.out.println("Is " + value1 + " and " + value2 + " present in the array: " + result);
    }

    public static boolean checkArray(int[] array, int first, int second) {
        boolean containsFirst = false;
        boolean containsSecond = false;
        for (int element : array) {
            if (element == first) {
                containsFirst = true;
            } else if (element == second) {
                containsSecond = true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return containsFirst && containsSecond;
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `int[] array = {1, 2, 1, 1};` `int[] array = {1, 4, 1, 1, 3};` `int[] array = {1, 1, 1};`

Comment: И что мне с этим делать?

Comment: прочитать условие задачи еще раз. [ 1 4 4 1 1 4 3 ]  возвращает true, а должно false

Comment: Спасибо, ребята, за решение, сам бы не догадался, еще не мой уровень.

Comment: В свое оправдание напишу лишь то, что решение забью ручками на память, без сочетаний клавиш Ctrl+C и Ctrl+V

Comment: lampa, добавил проверку. На здоровье

Comment: @DeMmAge вот теперь да)

Answer (score 2):

Бгг

```
public class Application {
    public static boolean checkArray(int[] array, int value1, int value2) {
        int len = array.length;

        String result = "";

        for (int j : array) {
            result += " " + j;
        }

        String replace = result.replace(" " + value1, "");
        String replace2 = replace.replace(" " + value2, "");

        return replace.length() != array.length * 2 && replace2.length() != replace.length() * 2 && replace2.isEmpty();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(checkArray(new int[] {1, 1, 4, 1}, 1, 4)); // true
        System.out.println(checkArray(new int[] {1, 1, 1, 1}, 1, 4)); // false
        System.out.println(checkArray(new int[] {4, 4, 4, 4}, 1, 4)); // false
        System.out.println(checkArray(new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4}, 1, 4)); // false
    }
}
```

Comment: @Александр Киласония ээ не надо этот ответ принимать))) Два других куда лучше!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CompositionArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {1, 1, 1, 1};
        int value1 = 1;
        int value2 = 4;
        System.out.println("Array: " + Arrays.toString(array));
        boolean result = checkArray(array, value1, value2);
        System.out.println("Is " + value1 + " and " + value2 + " present in the array: " + result);
    }

    public static boolean checkArray(int[] array, int first, int second) {
        boolean containsFirst = false;
        boolean containsSecond = false;
        for (int element : array) {
            if (element == first) {
                containsFirst = true;
            } else if (element == second) {
                containsSecond = true;
            }
        }
        return containsFirst && containsSecond;
    }
}
```

Comment: А чем этот ответ отличается от ответа DeMmAge? :) Плюс, тут алгоритм неправильный результат выдаст, если в массиве будет отличное от 1 или 4

Comment: @gil9red, все условия задачи выполняются на 100%)))

Comment: @АлександрКиласония вот этот  неверно выполняется {1, 2, 3, 4}

Comment: Это тоже `[ 1 4 4 1 1 4 3 ] -> false`?